La consulta con parámetros '(@Rut int,@Nombre nvarchar(4000))
Necesito ayuda ya que no se que mas opción puedo probar. Lo tuve que hacer así ya que me lo pidieron y el problema surge que hago conexiones mediante procedimientos almacenados pero este no estaba y me pidieron crearlo dentro de un archivo y no en la base de datos, investigue y aun así, muchas soluciones no funcionaron
  public static DataTable BuscarTecnico_BB(int Rut, string Nombre, string CadenaConexion)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(CadenaConexion))
        {
            conexion.Open(); 

            using (SqlCommand _comando = new SqlCommand())
            {
                _comando.Connection = conexion;
                _comando.CommandText = @"
            SELECT 
                tec_rut_tec,
                tec_dig_ver,
                tec_ide_tec,
                tec_nom_tec,
                tec_tel_fij,
                tec_tel_mov,
                tec_cor_ele,
                par_des_par AS Estado,
                tec_usr_res
       
            FROM TEC AS t
       
            INNER JOIN PAR AS p ON p.par_cod_tab = 1 AND p.par_cod_par = t.tec_cod_est
       
            WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,tec_rut_tec) LIKE CASE @Rut WHEN 0 THEN '%' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Rut) + '%' END
            AND   tec_nom_tec LIKE CASE @Nombre WHEN '' THEN tec_nom_tec ELSE @Nombre + '%' END
       
            ORDER BY tec_nom_tec";


                _comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rut", Rut);
                _comando.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = Nombre;
                


                using (SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(_comando))
                {
                    DataTable resultado = new DataTable();
                    adaptador.Fill(resultado);
                    return resultado;
                }
            }
        }
    }


No se entiende el problema y la solución que buscas. Lee [ask] y [mre] para mas ayuda.

Hola, tengo dudas en tu consulta, cual es el error que tienes, podrías agregar que error te genera el sistema? Sin este dato es muy complicado saber cual es el problema que posees.
